# Can you include a .cu extension header in a c++ header?

Tags: c++, cuda, header-files, undeclared-identifier

I have a .cu file that when compiled on its own, right click and select compile, it compiles just fine, but when I have another header file, a c++ header file, that calls this .cu file the build fails. The .cu file properties have been edited to build with the CUDA compiler. The errors that I am getting are 'blockIdx': undeclared identifier 'blockDim': undeclared identifier, etc.. basically errors that I would expect compiling cuda code with a c++ compiler. So is it possible to include a .cu cuda code in a c++ header?

Here is the .cu file:

Matrix.cu

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_device_runtime_api.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 32

using namespace std;



template<typename T> class Matrix
{
public:
typedef T value_type;
~Matrix();
Matrix();
Matrix(int rows, int columns);
int height;
int width;
int stride;
size_t size;

void CreateIdentity(Matrix<T>&I);
private:
vector<T> elements;
T* firstElement;
};


template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix()
{
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix()
{
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int rows, int columns)
{
height = rows;
width = columns;
stride = columns; //in row major order this is equal to the # of columns
elements.resize(rows*columns);
firstElement = elements.data();
size = height*width*sizeof(T);
}



__global__ void IdentityMatrixKernel(float* identity, int size)
{
int index_x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int index_y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

// map the two 2D indices to a single linear, 1D index
int grid_width = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
int index = index_y * grid_width + index_x;

// map the two 2D block indices to a single linear, 1D block index
//int result = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;

// write out the result

if (index % (size+1))
{
    identity[index] = 0;
}

else
{
    identity[index] = 1;
}
}


template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::CreateIdentity(Matrix<T>&I)
{
float* d_I;
int size1 = I.height;
int size2 = I.height*I.width*sizeof(float);

cudaMalloc(&d_I,size2);

dim3 block_size;
block_size.x = BLOCKSIZE;
block_size.y = BLOCKSIZE;

dim3 grid_size;
grid_size.x = size1/ block_size.x + 1;
grid_size.y = size1/ block_size.y + 1;

IdentityMatrixKernel<<<block_size,grid_size>>>(d_I,size1);

cudaMemcpy(I.GetPointer(),d_I,size2,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(d_I);
}
```

And here is the header file that #include "Matrix.cu"

Element.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Matrix.cu"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Element
{
public:
Element(void);
~Element(void);
Element(int iD, float k, vector<int> nodes);
Element(int iD, vector<int> nodes, int pId);

void SetElementType(DOF type);
DOF GetElementType();
int GetNodeId(int index);
int GetNodesPerElement();
int GetPartId();

void CalculateShapeFunctions(Matrix<int> spaceCoordinates);
void CalculateSShapeDerivative(Matrix<int> spaceCoordinates);
void CalculateTShapeDerivative(Matrix<int> spaceCoordinates);
Matrix<float> GetShapeFunctions();
float GetSShapeDerivative(int row, int column);
float GetTShapeDerivative(int row, int column);
void SetStrainDisplacement(Matrix<float> B);
Matrix<float> GetStrainDisplacement();

private:

int elementId;
float stiffness;
vector<int> nodeIds;
DOF elementType;
int partId;
Matrix<float> shapeFunctions;
Matrix<float> sShapeDerivative;
Matrix<float> tShapeDerivative;
Matrix<float> strainDisplacement;
};
```

EDIT:

So I have been directed to try and separate the template class member functions implementing cuda into a .cu file while keeping the template class definition and any template member functions not using cuda in the original header file. This does seem on the right path, c++ compiler compiles the .h file while the cuda compiler does the .cu, but I am having trouble getting rid of link errors. I understand that I need to explicitly instantiate my template class for the types I need in the .cu file to avoid link errors, but I seem to still get them.

I instantiated my template class at the end of the .cu file as follows:

```
template class Matrix<float>;
template class Matrix<int>;
template class Matrix<string>;
```

I am now getting link errors to the template member functions using cuda.

Comment: Just remove your Matrix class and implement it in an other file. c++ and cu code could call it without anyproblem.. And no it's not possible to include .cu

Comment: The problem with moving the member functions using cuda code to a separate .cu file is that I get link errors.

Comment: could you show your linking error and how you compile your file etc.. Show everything bout how you are compiling your whole program

Comment: I was able to get it to work. The methods using cuda didn't like three types of instantiated template classes and was bugging out. Good news though, all of the methods using cuda only required float types, and when I included the template instantiation for float in the .h file, the program built. Also, the matrices themselves constructed for any type that was sent to it not just float. Only the methods using cuda were forced to use float types.

Comment: @user3390212:please add your solution as an answer. You will later be able to accept that answer. This will get the question off the unanswered question list

Answer (score 1):

Answer: .cu files cannot be used as #include "file.cu" like header files because they will be compiled with the C++ compiler not cuda. The solution was to move anything implementing cuda into a separate .cu file while still keeping the definitions of the template functions inside the template class definition in the header, and adding an #include "file.h" in the file.cu. To solve any link errors with the template function declarations that were moved to a .cu file, an explicit instantiation of the template class was added to the bottom of the header file. Since only float types were used in the template functions using cuda, only an instantiation of type float was added: template class Matrix. The above solution compiled and ran perfectly.